# didn't stop at the break point in onActivityResult when returning from another activity

Tags: android, breakpoints

guys! I have a button in an activity, when clicked, will execute below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_IMAGE_ALBUMS);
```

it will open the albumn and let you select an image. but it didn't enter the break point in onActivityResult, the break point at the first line:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RESULT_IMAGE_ALBUMS) { //break point
        ...
        //get the image through uri, and show it on image view.
    }
}
```

what surprise me is the image does get displayed on the image view.

Anyone have any idea? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you set the RESULT_OK while returning from the activity?

Comment: when you are going to your second activity are you setting the result over there ??? I mean when you are going to a second activity from startActivityForResult(x,x), after you reach there you have to set teh result over there like 

     `your_activity_context.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);`

Answer (score 0):

If as you stated the image is displayed in the imageview, then something could be wrong on how you set your break point.
Just for testing, try to add Log and check if it is displayed in the logcat.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RESULT_IMAGE_ALBUMS) { //break point
        ...
        Log.e("", "Image returned!");
        //get the image through uri, and show it on image view.
    }
    else{
        Log.e("", "ResultCode = RESULT_CANCEL!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that. the code always got executed. When select some pictures, it will stop at the break point, but when select some supernatural pictures, it won't stop, and won't stop thereafter!

Comment: Okay try to add else statement as in my edit and check if it stops there.

Comment: Still no break, i give up. Thank you anyway.